# cx_Freeze ImportError: DLL load failed failed while importing _ctypes: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, cx-freeze, python-3.8

I compiled some Python scripts with cx_Freeze but compiled scripts giving me this error:

[image: click to see error]

`setup.py:`

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

executables = [
    Executable('USBAIO.py', base="Win32GUI", icon="Icons\\icon.ico"),
    Executable('ui.py', base="Win32GUI", icon="Icons\\icon.ico"),
    Executable("formatter.py", base="Win32GUI", icon="Icons\\cicon.ico"),
    Executable("updater.py", base="Win32GUI", icon="Icons\\uicon.ico"),
    Executable("permremove.py", base="Win32GUI", icon="Icons\\cicon.ico")
    ]

Packages = ["tkinter","functools", "time", "win32api",
                    "threading", "subprocess", "psutil", "os",
                    "shutil", "re", "requests", "sys", "ctypes",
                    "argparse", "google_drive_downloader",
                    "win32file", "win32con"
                    ]

Include = ["Icons", "version.txt", "icon.ico"]

setup(
    name="myapp",
    options={"build_exe":{"packages":Packages,"include_files":Include}},
    description = "myapp",
    executables = executables
)
```

> Python version: 3.8
>
> Windows: 8.1 Pro WMC
>
> cx_Freeze: 6.0b1

Comment: What happens if you add *cytpes* to the *Packages* list?

Comment: I've already added ctypes to Packages list.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say *\_ctypes* (not sure if possible, as it's not a package).

Comment: It still gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the answer. The error caused by a DLL that cx_Freeze couldn't grab.
When I copy the `libffi-7.dll` to `lib` folder my application works fine.
Here is my research: [research](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/523)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was caused by using conda install pyqt.

Uninstalling it and reinstalling using conda install -c anaconda pyqt fixed it.